# popup Video stream window in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, user-interface, tkinter

I want to display my camera stream in a different window when I clicked a button on my gui. When the camera stream is displayed the gui works fine, so I think that when I create a pop-up window with using `tkinter.Toplevel()`, maybe I can do that but I cannot configure the new pop-up window?

Is there any solution for this or suggestions?

```
def Button_A_Function():
top=tkinter.Toplevel()
 . . .
```

And here is the code for taking the videoStream from camera
`cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)`

```
while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: instead of `while True` you may need to use `top.after(millisecond, function)` to periodically run function which use `cap.read()`

Comment: see examples `tkinter-CV - minimal version` and `tkinter-CV - with buttons to start and stop` on my GitHub https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/cv2